# make JSON array from dynamic form data angular

Tags: angularjs, json

i have a dynamic form in angular. and i want to send the response as json. how do i generate JSON from the form?

here's the complete code,I have to get json, and post it to some api.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="dyf" ng-submit="submit()"> 

<form name="userFormOne" novalidate>
    <table>
      <tr class="form-group" ng-repeat="x in names">

        <td><label>{{ x.Field }}</label>
        </td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{x.Comment}}" required>
        </td>
      </tr>
     </table>{{data}}
    </form>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('dyf', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:5000/gu")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data;console.log(response.data);});

    $scope.data ={};



});


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) to bind input controls to data model. Then send model objects to server

Comment: @charlietfl how?

Comment: Suggest you study some tutorials. Stackoverflow isn't a tutorial service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In **AngularJs** we use **ng-model** to bind inputs value to our controller, **sample**:
>
> This full sample to figure out how to create a simple form, from array and how to send it as JSON to your API.
>
> **Note:** On submit check your console, and see the objects value.

```js
 var app = angular.module("app", []);

        app.controller("ctrl",
            function ($scope) {

                var options = [
                    { name: "a" },
                    { name: "b" },
                    { name: "c" }
                ];

                $scope.names = [
                    { id: 1, field: "insert name", name: "name", placeholder: "your name is", value:null, type:"text" },
                    { id: 2, field: "insert phone", name: "phone", placeholder: "your phone is", value: null, type: "tel" },
                    { id: 3, field: "insert age", name: "age", placeholder: "your age is", value: null, type: "number", min: 0, max: 20 },
                    { id: 4, field: "select country", name: "country", placeholder: "your country is", value: null, type: "select", options: options }
                ];

                $scope.sendMe = function() {
                    console.log($scope.names);
                }
            });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

</head>
<body>
    <form name="userFormOne" novalidate>
        <table>
            <tr class="form-group" ng-repeat="x in names">

                <td>
                    <label>{{ x.field }}</label>
                </td>
                <td ng-if="x.type != 'select'">
                    <input type="{{x.type}}" min="{{x.min}}" max="{{x.max}}" ng-model="x.value" name="{{x.name}}" placeholder="{{x.placeholder}}" ng-required="true">
                    {{x.value}}
                </td>
                <td ng-if="x.type == 'select'">
                    <select  ng-model="x.value" name="{{x.name}}" ng-options="item as item.name for item in x.options">
                    </select>
                    {{x.value}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <button ng-disabled="userFormOne.$invalid" ng-click="sendMe()">sendMe</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```